# Subset range with alpha numeric

Tags: r

I'm trying to define a subset in a column of data (actually want to make a subset with several different ranges).

I'm starting with:

`subset <- x[(x$y >= "J8500" & x$y < "J8900"), ]`

However, this excludes everything. left with 0 observations.

```
subset <- x[x$y >= "J8500", ]
```

does exclude all the variables that start with a `J` and are lower than 8500, but it includes some variables starting with other letters as well. for that command I would want only variables that start with J.

Ultimately, I would like to do something like the following:

```
subset <- x[(x$y >= "J8500" & x$y < "J8900") | (x$y >= "96400" & x$y <"96599") | (x$y >= "Q0083" & x$y < "Q0085"), ]
```

I don't have much coding background, hope that made sense.

Comment: Can you post an example of your data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr()` to extract substrings. So if you only want entries that start with "J", you can use something like this:

```
yy <- c("KK","JK","KJ")
substr(yy,1,1)=="J"
```

After that, you may need to split your strings using `substr()` and then convert the second part from strings to numerical variables using `as.numeric()` for them to be comparable as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Is `x$y` a factor?   If so, that could be causing the error.

Try either converting y to numeric

```
 x$y <- as.character(x$y)
```

Or wrapping the call to x$y in as.character()

```
subset <- x[as.character(x$y) >= "J8500" & as.character(x$y) < "J8900", ]
```